# Do Things While a Bash Script is Running

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop

I have a very simple bash script; call it `test.sh` for practical purposes:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sleep 5s

echo "Program is done."
```

I have another script that must take statistics with the `/usr/bin/time` command, for which I have set the `cf` alias; call this script `statistics.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Make sure to add the aliases.
shopt -s expand_aliases
source ~/.bash_aliases

# Get the command name.
name=${1:2}
echo "Executing script: $1"
echo "Name of script: $name"

# Run the script and get the process id.
cf $1 &
procID=$!

# While the $1 script is running do.
while [ <The script with id $1 is running>  ]
do
   echo "Here"
   sleep 1s
done

wait

# Exit message.
echo "Done running the program."
```

I have failed to make the `while` loop (properly) work; i.e., print "Here" 5 (or 4?) times.

### Running the Program

I run the program as:

```
./statistics.sh './test.sh'
```

Whenever I am running it without the `while` loop it works perfectly, without printing the desired strings...of course.

### What I Have Tried

I am lost in the sea of literature and 'solutions', but I have tried to set the `<The script with id $1 is running>` as:

- `kill -0 $1 2> /dev/null` (and variations of)
- I have tried to use the `trap` command, but I don't think that I understand it properly and thus it's not working.

Comment: To the extent that you claim to have "tried" `kill -0` and found that it doesn't work, we need enough details to reproduce the failure mode ourselves. It _is_ the correct solution; so to diagnose why it doesn't work _for you_ we need to know exactly how you're trying to use it and exactly how it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while kill -0 "$procID" 2>/dev/null
do
    echo Here
    sleep 1
done
```

If the condition is a command, you don't put it inside `[]`. `[` is an alias for the `test` command, it's used for testing conditional expressions, not the status of other commands.

Answer (score 1):

1. launch the program into the background
2. launch the "here" loop into the background as well
3. wait for the program to complete
4. then kill the here loop

```bash
cf "$1" &
procID=$!

( while true; do echo "Here"; sleep 1s; done ) &
loopID=$!

wait "$procID"
kill "$loopID"
```

We can give it some more pizzazz:

```bash
(
    spinner=('/' '-' '\' '|')
    # or: spinner=(' ' '░' '▒' '▓' '█' '▓' '▒' '░')
    # or: spinner=(' ' '○' '◎' '●' '◎' '○')
    n=${#spinner[@]}
    i=0
    while true; do
        printf '\r%s ' "${spinner[(i++)%n]}"
        sleep 0.1s
    done
) &
```